# Use a variable for the index of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, indexing

Here is my code:

```
var span = getSpanWithClass("galleria-current");
var slideNumber = span.innerHTML
var imageIDDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshowImage");
var singleimageidDiv = imageIDDivs[slideNumber]
```

If I use this, `sigleImageidDiv` doesn't have anything in it. If I just put 0 or 1 in like this:

```
var singleimageidDiv = imageIDDivs[1]
```

It works fine. `slideNumber` is `1`, in my test cases.

I have tried these as well:

```
var singleimageidDiv = imageIDDivs[Number(slideNumber)]

var singleimageidDiv = imageIDDivs[parseInt(slideNumber)]
```

What is the proper way to use a variable as the index of an array?

Comment: If you're copying the code directly from the source, you're missing semi-colons at the end of most of your lines. You should fix the syntax of your code before you start looking at other reasons why it might not be working.

Comment: Semicolons are not required in javascript; however, it is definitely good practice to use them.

Comment: @JoshMein. Here comes _am not I am_ comments saying: _"I uses semicolons only at Stack Overflow..."_

Comment: What is the innerHTML of that span? That would be the information of interest to solve your problem.

Comment: @Bergi, It's funny no-one ask it until now, including me... :)

Comment: @user1308743. Then it should work. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h86gn/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse to int with a radix.

This is the proper way of doing it:

```
imageIDDivs[parseInt(slideNumber, 10)];
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h86gn/)
If it doesn't work, then your problem is somewhere else.

---

BTW indexes work with strings as well.
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h86gn/1/)

Comment: I tried parseInt without the ,10 and it did not work. with the ,10, it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @user1308743. With which browser did you try it? 10 is the default radix. can you create a not working DEMO at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` returns the string inside the element, so if even if you have a number inside your element, it'll be returned as a string, that's why when you use that variable as an index for your array, you don't get a result.
Using parseInt is an acceptable solution, you could also just do something like `span.innerHTML * 1`, that would force JS to treat the string as an integer.

Comment: Array indizes are strings as every other property names. No need for a number.

Comment: @Berji Didn't know that!  Shoot.

Comment: Almost, but not exactly. Arrays are objects, and thus, if you use a string as an index, you actually add a property that you could retrieve using that same string index. That being said, `"1"` and `1` are two different indizes for an array.

Comment: Are they?  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp8cP/) seems to disagree, but maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: @apsillers Your example works for me too, but everything I've read about JS says otherwise, don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @Deleteman: What have you read and where? All non-string values will be converted to strings before being used as property accessors. Arrays only have some special behavior when that string looks like an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have an error in your `getSpanWithClass` function.